# Delete row of found result from VLOOKUP function

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I made a userform where you can look for a word and it will return the found word (using Vlookup), you can add a new word with a definition to the database (btw, the database are just two columns: "word" and "definiton").

I also want to create a delete function so the user can search for a word, if the system found a word in the database it will ask if it is the right word with the right definition and then it will delete the row from the word and the definition (or just the word and the definition)

This was my plan:

> search for a word --> is this the word? --> if yes, delete the word and its definition

I tried to vlookup the word and then get the adress of the vlookup result to delete it, but that didn't work.

Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Always helps if you [edit] your question with the code you've tried. Btw, `Range.Find` or `Application.Match` might be better here than vlookup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trying to understand your need, here is what you can try

```
Sub Find2Delete()
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Cells.Find(AWord, , XlFindLookIn.xlValues, XlLookAt.xlWhole)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        if MsgBox ("Delete?", vbYesNo) = vbYes then rng.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below logic:

```
For i = LastRow To FirstRow+1
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(Sheet.Cells(i, Column).Value, WordToFind, 0)) Then

            Sheet.Rows(i).Delete

   End If
Next i
```